# C++ Function to find the min+max value element in a vector

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ so I am very new to this.

I have a vector `vector<int> pricelist{30,10,16,25,13};`that's stored in a main class.

I want to implement a function `lowestNHighestPrices()` to return a `Prices` object that gives me the index value of the highest and lowest values in the vector (i.e. 0 and 1 respectively).

```
class Prices {
  protected:
   int lowestPrice;
   int highestPrice;

  public:
   Prices(const int lowestPriceIn, const int highestPriceIn)
       : lowestPrice(lowestPriceIn), highestPrice(highestPriceIn) {
   }

   int getlowestPrice() const {
       return lowestPrice;
   }

   int gethighestPrice() const {
       return highestPrice;
   }
};
```

the method will be called by this line of code `Prices prices = lowestNHighestPrices(prices);`

I am not entirely sure of the syntax, is there a keyword of some sort I can use with the getter methods so that I can obtain the highest and lowest values from the vector? Such that `getLowestPrice() == 0` and `getHighestPrice() == 1`?

Comment: Write a loop that iterates over the vector, and assign for the smallest value and the largest value. Or, if you don't care about time, use `std::min_element` (max_element)

Comment: sorry I had a typo in the code I placed here, it was meant to return lowestPrices and highestPrices...not sure why I wrote time.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, you can use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`. The following code (with an update of the `Prices` class for the empty list) makes one list iteration.

```
class Prices {
  protected:
   int lowestPrice;
   int highestPrice;
   bool isValid;

public:
   Prices() : lowestPrice(), highestPrice(), isValid(false) {}
   Prices(const int lowestPriceIn, const int highestPriceIn)
     : lowestPrice(lowestPriceIn), highestPrice(highestPriceIn) {}
   void updateWith(int val)
     { if (!isValid) {
         lowestPrice = highestPrice = val;
         isValid = true;
       }
       else if (val < lowestPrice)
         lowestPrice = val;
       else if (val > highestPrice)
         highestPrice = val;
     }
};

Prices lowestNHighestPrices(const vector<int>& pricelist) {
  Prices result;
  for (auto val : pricelist)
    result.updateWith(val);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11 available (and you should), just use [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element):

```
Prices lowestNHighestPrices(const vector<int>& pricelist)
{
   assert( !pricelist.empty() ); // just in case
   auto res = std::minmax_element(
      pricelist.cbegin(),
      pricelist.cend()
   );
   return Prices( *res.first, *res.second );
}
```

Comment: I do have C++11 but whenever I try compiling the code, I get an error telling me that minmax_element is not a member of std.

Comment: Can't see the link. And yes I did try #include <algorithm> and it didn't work. But I don't think I should be using std::minmax_element. I have to test my code based on code in a .cpp "Test" file and I am not allowed to change anything.

Comment: You don't see the link ??? In my answer, just click on `std::minmax_element`. This will bring you on the cppreference.com relevant page. And I don't really understand why you shoudn't use that, as it is the most efficient solution. But it's up to you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Return a `std::pair<int, int>`.

```
std::pair<int, int> lowestNHighestPrices() const
{
   return {lowestPrice, highestPrice};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your class already has a public interface/methods to your high and low price values. returning another structure from it or using a pass by reference parameter is although a possible solution but looks pointless in this situation. and use of std::pair, another class/structure, should be preferred where more generic code is intended, such as containers, due to its abstract naming to access member variables.